# Cut image until you find a different color

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm implementing certain features for my program and one of them is when I extract an image I want to cut it to one pixel before the different color

I mean, this is the original image I get

[image]

And I need to cut it down to about this

[image]

I use this because it's an encrypted code that I need to read with the tresseract, if I read it with the tresseract otherwise it doesn't return the expected result, but by limiting it only to that image if it returns the text correctly

I haven't implemented python code yet because I don't know how to handle these cases, so I don't give examples of what I've done.

I don't know if this is the most practical thing to do or if the tresseract should be adjusted properly.

Since in tresseract I have only used these commands to configure it

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="spa",config="--psm 4 tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.%/")
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would do this is to use the PIL library. To get pixel values like this.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.jpg') 
pix = im.load()
print(pix[x,y])
```

Then I would loop through all the pixels and find once that aren't near to the black colour you have and add them to a new list. And then i would put that into a new file again using PIL.

To answer your question this is the code to loop through the pixels and checking if they are not black. Of course you still need the above code.

```
for i in range(im.size[0]): #looping for each pixel of y
    for n in range(im.size[1]): #looping for each pixel of x
        print(pix[i,n])
        if pix[i,n][0] < 10 and pix[i,n][1] < 10 and pix[i,n][2] < 10: #checking all the RGB values are under 10
            print('Not black')
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response,
ok you could help me with the issue of going through the pixels, because if I have worked with PIL, but I do not have enough experience, because maybe I change the color to black for another that highlights me more or something, but I do not know how to take the step

Comment: @LuisMorales I have edited the question with some code that should get you of the floor. feel free to ask any more questions.